# many labels on windows form - make performance better (calendar)

Tags: vb.net, performance, label, panel

I do have lots of labels on a panel for a calender (see picture).
365 per person and I would like draw a calendar for approx. 10 Persons. That are 3650 labels.

The performance has worsened, i have to wait a few seconds when i move the slide bar or when i move the windows form. 
What can i do? Is there a better way instead of using labels?

Thanks in advance.[image: Calendar with labels]

Comment: You can use GDI+ to draw text and/or shapes directly on the form or some other control.

Comment: yes that really works, thanks. But now there is a new problem:

When i scroll on my panel, the drawed area will be deleted...

Comment: Where did you put your code?

Comment: Anything you draw using GDI+ gets deleted every time the form or control gets repainted, which is why you need to draw it every time the form or control gets repainted, which is why you need to ALWAYS do the drawing in the `Paint` event handler of the form or control and use the `Graphics` object provided.